# Tutorial: How to use TeX/MathJax to render math notation?

Tags: discussion, faq, mathjax

$\mathrm{\TeX}$ is a markup language that allows us to insert content like equations and tables. MathJax is the add-in that StackExchange uses to render $\mathrm{\TeX}$ markup into $\mathrm{\TeX}$ graphics.

Using $\mathrm{\TeX}$ is simple:

1. Put `$` before-and-after $\mathrm{\TeX}$ markup to instruct MathJax to render it.

   - Example: Typing `$x+1$` into a post renders $x+1$.
2. Alternatively, put `$$` before-and-after $\mathrm{\TeX}$ markup to instruct MathJax to render it centered on a new line.

   - Example:  Typing `$$x+1$$` into a post renders $$x+1$$

Answers below discuss more things that can be done with $\mathrm{\TeX}$.

---

#### See also

1. Similar guides:

   - [Wikipedia's guide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula)
   - [SE.Math's guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)
2. [MathJax's official website](https://www.mathjax.org/)

   - [documentation with commands listed](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/macros/)
3. [StackExchange for TeX/LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)
4. ["MathJax"](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax) on GitHub
5. Wikipedia: ["TeX"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX);  ["LaTeX"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX);  ["MathJax"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathJax)

---

This question's meant to be a lot like the one at SE.Mathematics.Meta: "[MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)". It's posted separately here to both give this SE its own version of it (making it easier to find and such) and also since there's likely going to be some variation in what features/commands users would be interested in here vs. at SE.Mathematics. That said, it'd make sense for responses to this question to have a similar formatting and often to cover the same content.

I'd suggest contributors write up one feature per answer, giving each a standardized title, rendering of the relevant $\mathrm{\TeX} ,$ and the `code markup` for it.

Answer (score 15):

## [Bra-ket notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra-ket_notation)

Related:  ["How does bra-ket notation work?"](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-does-bra-ket-notation-work).

**Bra:**  $\left< x \right|$

```
\left< x \right|
```

---

**Ket:**  $\left| x \right>$

```
\left| x \right>
```

---

**Bra-ket**:  $\left< x \middle| y \right>$

```
\left< x \middle| y \right>
```

**Bra-ket, extended:**  $\left< x \middle| y \middle| z \right>$

```
\left< x \middle| y \middle| z \right>
```

---

**Tensor Product:**  $\left| x \right> \otimes \left| y \right>$

```
\left| x \right> \otimes \left| y \right>
```

---

**Defining commands**

The notation can get tedious in large amounts of $\mathrm{\TeX} ,$ so it can be easier to define a `\newcommand` if writing a lot.

If you include

```
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\left<#1\right|}\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|#1\right>}\newcommand{\bk}[2]{\left<#1\middle|#2\right>}\newcommand{\bke}[3]{\left<#1\middle|#2\middle|#3\right>}
```

at the start of your $\mathrm{\TeX} ,$ then it defines the commands `\bra{}`, `\ket{}`, `\bk{}{}`, and `\bke{}{}{}`.  Thereafter, you can use them easily:

- `\bra{x}` renders as $\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\left< #1 \right|}\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left| #1 \right>}\newcommand{\bk}[2]{\left< #1 \middle| #2 \right>}\bra{x}$.
- `\ket{x}` renders as $\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\left< #1 \right|}\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left| #1 \right>}\newcommand{\bk}[2]{\left< #1 \middle| #2 \right>}\ket{x}$.
- `\bk{x}{y}` renders as $\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\left< #1 \right|}\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left| #1 \right>}\newcommand{\bk}[2]{\left< #1 \middle| #2 \right>}\bk{x}{y}$.
- `\bke{x}{y}{z}` renders as $\newcommand{\bke}[3]{\left<#1\middle|#2\middle|#3\right>}\bke{x}{y}{z}$

Un-code-golf'd, this code's:

```
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\left< #1 \right|}
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left| #1 \right>}
\newcommand{\bk}[2]{\left< #1 \middle| #2 \right>}
\newcommand{\bke}[3]{\left< #1 \middle| #2 \middle| #3 \right>}
```

---

**Alternatives to using `<`, `|`, `>`**

1. `\langle` can be used instead of `<` and renders as $\langle$.
2. `\rangle` can be used instead of `>` and renders as $\rangle$.
3. `\vert` can be used instead of `|` and renders as $\vert$.

   - Other variants include: `\lvert`, `\rvert`, and `\mid`.
4. These alternatives can be easier since they don't *require* (but may employ) `\left`, `\middle`, `\right` qualifiers.

   - `\langle x \vert`: $\langle x \vert$
   - `\left\langle x \right\vert`: $\left\langle x \right\vert$
5. However, the `\left`, `\middle`, `\right` qualifiers can make the rendering cleaner.

   - `\langle v \vert  \sum_{{\forall}i{\in}{\mathbb{N}}} \vert e_i \rangle` looks weird:

   $$\langle v \vert  \sum_{{\forall}i{\in}{\mathbb{N}}} \vert e_i \rangle$$

   - `\left\langle v \middle\vert  \sum_{{\forall}i{\in}{\mathbb{N}}} \middle\vert e_i \right\rangle` fixes it:

   $$
   \left\langle v \middle\vert  \sum_{{\forall}i{\in}{\mathbb{N}}} \middle\vert e_i \right\rangle
   $$

   - `\left< v \middle|  \sum_{{\forall}i{\in}{\mathbb{N}}} \middle| e_i \right>` is easier:

   $$\left< v \middle|  \sum_{{\forall}i{\in}{\mathbb{N}}} \middle| e_i \right>$$

Answer (score 8):

## [QCircuit](http://physics.unm.edu/CQuIC/Qcircuit/) / [XYJax](https://github.com/sonoisa/XyJax/blob/master/README.md) / [Xy-Pic](https://www.tug.org/applications/Xy-pic/):

Qcircuit is a set of macros to generate quantum ciruits, it uses a couple of accessory extensions and works with MathJax.

Here's [an example](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Quantum_teleportation_circuit.svg) (written using Tex, over at Wikipedia):

```
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 \Qcircuit @C=1em @R=.7em {
  \lstick{\ket{\psi}_C}   & \ctrl{1} & \gate{H} & \meter                  & \control \cw \\
  \lstick{\ket{\Phi}^+_A} & \targ    & \meter   & \control \cw \cwx[1] \\
  \lstick{\ket{\Phi}^+_B} & \qw      & \qw      & \targ                   & \control \cwx[-2] \qw & \rstick{\ket{\psi}_B} \qw
 }
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Such code, written in a MathJax compatible format, would create this image (which would be editable):

[image: Quantum Teleportation]

Apparently the [Stacks](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01W7) website has QCircuit, and there's [mention of it over at Tex.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397889/how-to-write-qcircuit-code-for-the-following-figure); but it doesn't seem to be working (enabled) here. If someone could figure out how to trigger it on a webpage (with a 'require' command) that would be awesome. Please comment or edit this answer with a tested answer.

[Q-circuit Tutorial](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0406003) at arXiv.

Comment: Related: [How to re-create the following circuit image?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4066) & links therein.

Answer (score 5):

## Basics of typesetting in MathJax

<sub>Mathematics Stack Exchange has a [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) but they are free to alter or delete it without consulting us. Let's have our own, using their template. Constructive edits below this line most welcome.</sub>

<sub>**This list is greatly improved over the linked-to list which has far less information than what is included here.**</sub>

---

<sub>(Deutsch: [MathJax: LaTeX Basic Tutorial und Referenz](https://www.mathelounge.de/509545/mathjax-latex-basic-tutorial-und-referenz-deutsch))</sub>

If you don't find exactly what you are looking for in this first section there are links near the bottom of this answer which enumerate every possible MathJax command. This answer can't include every symbol as it would bog down page loading times.

1. To see how any formula was written in any question or answer, including this one, right-click on the expression it and choose "Show Math As > TeX Commands". (When you do this, the '$' will not display. Make sure you add these. See the next point.)
2. **For inline formulas, enclose the formula in `$...$`.  For displayed formulas, use `$$...$$`.**
   These render differently. For example,
   type
   `$\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 = \frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1)}{6}$`
   to show $\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 = \frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1)}{6}$ (which is inline mode) or  type

   `$$\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 = \frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1)}{6}$$`

   to show
   $$\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 = \frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1)}{6}$$
   (which is display mode).
3. For **Greek letters**, use `\alpha`, `\beta`, …, `\omega`: $\alpha, \beta, … \omega$.  For uppercase, use `\Gamma`, `\Delta`, …, `\Omega`: $\Gamma, \Delta, …, \Omega$.
4. For **superscripts and subscripts**, use `^` and `_`.  For example, `x_i^2`: $x_i^2$, `\log_2 x`: $\log_2 x$.
5. **Groups**. Superscripts, subscripts, and other operations apply only to the next “group”. A “group” is either a single symbol, or any formula surrounded by curly braces `{`…`}`.  If you do `10^10`, you will get a surprise: $10^10$. But `10^{10}` gives what you probably wanted: $10^{10}$. Use curly braces to delimit a formula to which a superscript or subscript applies: `x^5^6` is an error;  `{x^y}^z` is ${x^y}^z$, and `x^{y^z}` is $x^{y^z}$. Observe the difference between `x_i^2` $x_i^2$ and `x_{i^2}` $x_{i^2}$.
6. **Parentheses** Ordinary symbols `()[]` make parentheses and brackets $(2+3)[4+4]$. Use `\{` and `\}` for curly braces $\{\}$.

   These do *not* scale with the formula in between, so if you write `(\frac{\sqrt x}{y^3})` the parentheses will be too small: $(\frac{\sqrt x}{y^3})$.    Using `\left(`…`\right)` will make the sizes adjust automatically to the formula they enclose: `\left(\frac{\sqrt x}{y^3}\right)` is $\left(\frac{\sqrt x}{y^3}\right)$.

   `\left` and`\right` apply to all the following sorts of parentheses: `(` and `)` $(x)$, `[` and `]` $[x]$, `\{` and `\}` $\{ x \}$, `|` $|x|$, `\vert` $\vert x \vert$, `\Vert` $\Vert x \Vert$, `\langle` and `\rangle` $\langle x \rangle$,  `\lceil` and `\rceil` $\lceil x \rceil$, and `\lfloor` and `\rfloor` $\lfloor x \rfloor$. `\middle` can be used to add additional dividers. There are also invisible parentheses, denoted by `.`: `\left.\frac12\right\rbrace` is $\left.\frac12\right\rbrace$.

   If manual size adjustments are required:
   `\Biggl(\biggl(\Bigl(\bigl((x)\bigr)\Bigr)\biggr)\Biggr)` gives
   $\Biggl(\biggl(\Bigl(\bigl((x)\bigr)\Bigr)\biggr)\Biggr)$.
7. **Sums and integrals** `\sum` and `\int`; the subscript is the lower limit and the superscript is the upper limit, so for example `\sum_1^n` $\sum_1^n$. Don't forget `{`…`}` if the limits are more than a single symbol.  For example, `\sum_{i=0}^\infty i^2` is $\sum_{i=0}^\infty i^2$. Similarly, `\prod` $\prod$, `\int` $\int$, `\bigcup` $\bigcup$, `\bigcap` $\bigcap$, `\iint` $\iint$, `\iiint` $\iiint$.
8. **Fractions** There are two ways to make these. `\frac ab` applies to the next two groups, and produces $\frac ab$; for more complicated numerators and denominators use `{`…`}`: `\frac{a+1}{b+1}` is $\frac{a+1}{b+1}$. If the numerator and denominator are complicated, you may prefer `\over`, which splits up the group that it is in: `{a+1\over b+1}` is ${a+1\over b+1}$.
9. **Fonts**

   - Use `\mathbb` or `\Bbb` for "blackboard bold": $\mathbb{CHNQRZ}$.
   - Use `\mathbf` for boldface: $\mathbf{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$  $\mathbf{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$.
   - Use `\mathtt` for "typewriter" font: $\mathtt{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$ $\mathtt{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$.
   - Use `\mathrm` for roman font: $\mathrm{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$  $\mathrm{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$.
   - Use `\mathsf` for sans-serif font: $\mathsf{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$  $\mathsf{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$.
   - Use `\mathcal` for "calligraphic" letters: $\mathcal{ ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$
   - Use `\mathscr` for script letters: $\mathscr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$
   - Use `\mathfrak` for "Fraktur" (old German style) letters: $\mathfrak{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ} \mathfrak{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$.
10. **Radical signs** Use `sqrt`, which adjusts to the size of its argument: `\sqrt{x^3}` $\sqrt{x^3}$; `\sqrt[3]{\frac xy}` $\sqrt[3]{\frac xy}$. For complicated expressions, consider using `{...}^{1/2}` instead.
11. Some **special functions** such as "lim", "sin", "max", "ln", and so on are normally set in roman font instead of italic font. Use `\lim`, `\sin`, etc. to make these: `\sin x` $\sin x$, not `sin x` $sin x$. Use subscripts to attach a notation to `\lim`: `\lim_{x\to 0}` $$\lim_{x\to 0}$$
12. There are a very large number of **special symbols and notations**, too many to list here; see [this shorter listing](http://pic.plover.com/MISC/symbols.pdf), or [this exhaustive listing](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf). Some of the most common include:

    - `\lt \gt \le \ge \neq` $\lt\, \gt\, \le\, \ge\, \neq$.  You can use `\not` to put a slash through almost anything: `\not\lt` $\not\lt$ but it often looks bad (also see two lines down).
    - `\lessapprox` ⪅ `\gtrapprox` ⪆ `\lesssim` ≲ `\gtrsim` ≳
    - `\lnapprox` ⪉ `\gnapprox` ⪊ `\lnsim` ⋦ `\gnsim` ⋧
    - `\times \div \pm \mp` $\times\, \div\, \pm\, \mp$. `\cdot` is a centered dot: $x\cdot y$
    - `\cup \cap \setminus \subset \subseteq \subsetneq \supset \in \notin \emptyset \varnothing` $\cup\, \cap\, \setminus\, \subset\, \subseteq \,\subsetneq \,\supset\, \in\, \notin\, \emptyset\, \varnothing$
    - `{n+1 \choose 2k}` or `\binom{n+1}{2k}` ${n+1 \choose 2k}$
    - `\to \rightarrow \leftarrow \Rightarrow \Leftarrow \mapsto` $\to\, \rightarrow\, \leftarrow\, \Rightarrow\, \Leftarrow\, \mapsto$
    - `\land \lor \lnot \forall \exists \top \bot \vdash \vDash` $\land\, \lor\, \lnot\, \forall\, \exists\, \top\, \bot\, \vdash\, \vDash$
    - `\star \ast \oplus \circ \bullet` $\star\, \ast\, \oplus\, \circ\, \bullet$
    - `\approx \sim \simeq \cong \equiv \prec \lhd` $\approx\, \sim \, \simeq\, \cong\, \equiv\, \prec, \lhd$.
    - `\infty \aleph_0` $\infty\, \aleph_0$ `\nabla \partial` $\nabla\, \partial$ `\Im \Re` $\Im\, \Re$
    - For modular equivalence, use `\pmod` like this: `a\equiv b\pmod n` $a\equiv b\pmod n$.
    - `\ldots` is the dots in $a_1, a_2, \ldots ,a_n$ `\cdots` is the dots in  $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n$
    - Some Greek letters have variant forms:
      `\epsilon \varepsilon` $\epsilon\, \varepsilon$, `\phi \varphi` $\phi\, \varphi$, and others. Script lowercase l is `\ell` $\ell$.

    [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) lets you draw a symbol on a web page and then lists the $\TeX$ symbols that seem to resemble it.  These are not guaranteed to work in MathJax but are a good place to start.  To check that a command is supported, note that MathJax.org maintains a [list of currently supported $\LaTeX$ commands](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#supported-latex-commands), and one can also check Dr. Carol JVF Burns's page of [$\TeX$ Commands Available in MathJax](http://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) or the list on Michael Downes "[Math Symbol and Math Fonts](http://www.pbx-brasil.com/Pesquisa/Ferramentas/Latex/mathjax/martinkeefe/mathjax3.html)" website.
13. **Spaces** MathJax usually decides for itself how to space formulas, using a complex set of rules. Putting extra literal spaces into formulas  will not change the amount of space MathJax puts in: `a␣b` and `a␣␣␣␣b` are  both $a    b$. To add more space, use `\,` for a thin space $a\,b$; `\;` for a wider space $a\;b$.  `\quad` and `\qquad` are large spaces: $a\quad b$, $a\qquad b$.

To reduce the space between a series of MathJax commands and a following word (doesn't work well with punctuation) use `\!` as many times as necessary.

To set plain text, use `\text{…}`: $\{x\in s\mid x\text{ is extra large}\}$. You can nest `$…$` inside of `\text{…}`.

14. **Accents and diacritical marks** Use `\hat` for a single symbol $\hat x$, `\widehat` for a larger formula $\widehat{xy}$. If you make it too wide, it will look silly. Similarly, there are `\bar` $\bar x$ and `\overline` $\overline{xyz}$, and `\vec` $\vec x$ and `\overrightarrow` $\overrightarrow{xy}$ and `\overleftrightarrow` $\overleftrightarrow{xy}$. For dots, as in $\frac d{dx}x\dot x =  \dot x^2 +  x\ddot x$,  use `\dot` and `\ddot`.

Accents from "[Math symbols and math fonts](http://www.pbx-brasil.com/Pesquisa/Ferramentas/Latex/mathjax/martinkeefe/mathjax3.html)" by Michael Downes:

`\acute{x}` $\acute{x}$ `\bar{x}` $\bar{x}$ `\vec{x}` $\vec{x}$ `\widetilde{xxx}` $\widetilde{xxx}$ `\grave{x}` $\grave{x}$ `\breve{x}` $\breve{x}$

`\dot{x}` $\dot{x}$ `\widehat{xxx}` $\widehat{xxx}$ `\ddot{x}` $\ddot{x}$ `\check{x}` $\check{x}$ `\ddot{x}` $\ddot{x}$ `\tilde{x}` $\tilde{x}$

`\hat{x}` $\hat{x}$ `\dddot{x}` $\dddot{x}$

15. Special characters used for MathJax interpreting can be escaped using the `\` character: `\$` $\$$, `\{` $\{$, `\_` $\_$, etc. If you want `\` itself, you should use `\backslash` $\backslash$, because `\\` is for a new line.

Additional examples from math.stackexchange.com showing how to draw commutative diagrams using \array or \newcommand:

[Example 1](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2326/510296):

```
$$ 
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!} 
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.} 
% 
\begin{array}{llllllllllll} 0 & \ra{f_1} & A & \ra{f_2} & B & \ra{f_3} & C & \ra{f_4} & D & \ra{f_5} & 0 \\ 
\da{g_1} & & \da{g_2} & & \da{g_3} & & \da{g_4} & & \da{g_5} & & \da{g_6} \\ 
0 & \ra{h_1} & 0 & \ra{h_2} & E & \ra{h_3} & F & \ra{h_4} & 0 & \ra{h_5} & 0 \\ 
\end{array} 
$$
```

$$ 
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!} 
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.} 
% 
\begin{array}{llllllllllll} 0 & \ra{f_1} & A & \ra{f_2} & B & \ra{f_3} & C & \ra{f_4} & D & \ra{f_5} & 0 \\ 
\da{g_1} & & \da{g_2} & & \da{g_3} & & \da{g_4} & & \da{g_5} & & \da{g_6} \\ 
0 & \ra{h_1} & 0 & \ra{h_2} & E & \ra{h_3} & F & \ra{h_4} & 0 & \ra{h_5} & 0 \\ 
\end{array} 
$$

[Example 2](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2325/510296):

```
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
0 & \xrightarrow{i} & A & \xrightarrow{f} & B & \xrightarrow{q} & C & \xrightarrow{d} & 0 \\
\downarrow & \searrow & \downarrow & \nearrow & \downarrow & \searrow & \downarrow & \nearrow & \downarrow \\
0 & \xrightarrow{j} & D & \xrightarrow{g} & E & \xrightarrow{r} & F & \xrightarrow{e} & 0
\end{array}
$$
```

$$
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
0 & \xrightarrow{i} & A & \xrightarrow{f} & B & \xrightarrow{q} & C & \xrightarrow{d} & 0 \\
\downarrow & \searrow & \downarrow & \nearrow & \downarrow & \searrow & \downarrow & \nearrow & \downarrow \\
0 & \xrightarrow{j} & D & \xrightarrow{g} & E & \xrightarrow{r} & F & \xrightarrow{e} & 0
\end{array}
$$

---

The word on Tables: [Is there Markdown to create tables?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-markdown-to-create-tables) - ASCII only, *real* Tables were denied.

Our whitelisted subset of HTML: [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites)

The [enormous list of $\TeX$ commands allowed in MathJax](http://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm).

[Michael Downes](http://www.pbx-brasil.com/Pesquisa/Ferramentas/Latex/mathjax/martinkeefe/mathjax1.html) of the American Mathematical Society has a useful MathJax website.

Another plethora of tips are offered on the [LaTeX - Mathematics: Fractions  and Binomials Wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Fractions_and_Binomials).

Hacking the [quod erat demonstrandum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D.) symbol is discussed here: "[\qed for MathJax here on stackexchange](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3582/qed-for-mathjax-here-on-stackexchange)" - Spoiler: `$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$`

$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

---

**Note:** It is important that this post be reasonably short and not suffer from too much bloat. To include more topics, please create short addenda and post them as answers instead of inserting them into this post.

Answer (score 3):

## Typesetting chemistry in MathJax

**Source**: [Quantum Computing SE meta: Formatting chemical formulae and reactions](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136/formatting-chemical-formulae-and-reactions)

> The LaTeX package `mhchem` is not activated here, by default. However,
>   you can load it yourself, by using the command `\require{\mhchem}`
>   (you need to use it only once on a page).
>
> Example: `\require{\mhchem}\ce{H2O}` generates
>   $\require{\mhchem}\ce{H2O}$.
>
> Courtesy: [@DavidCervone](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10069/enabling-mhchem#comment37970_10069) on Physics SE

---

<sub>Chemistry Stack Exchange has a community wiki by @ManishEarth titled [How can I format math/chemistry expressions here?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) which documents the MathJax commands for chemistry. Since they are free to alter/delete their copy without consulting us, let's have our own, using their template. Constructive edits below this line most welcome.</sub>

### Getting started

On chemistry.SE, we use [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) to format mathematical as well as chemical equations and similar expressions in questions, answers, and comments. MathJax allows us to typeset expressions using $\LaTeX$ notation.

To use MathJax, enclose your math within single (`$...$`) or double (`$$...$$`) dollar signs. Single dollar signs make the math *inline*, for example, `Let $x$ be a variable` gives:

> Let $x$ be a variable.

On the other hand, double dollar signs make the math a block element. It gets its own line, and is slightly larger. For example, `The equation of motion is as follows: $$v=u+at$$ It is a SUVAT equation` gives:

> The equation of motion is as follows: $$v=u+at$$ It is a SUVAT equation

Note that, in math mode, MathJax ignores the spaces you type, e.g. `$a b$` yields $a b$. MathJax formats expressions the way it is common in mathematics texts. However, the printing rules for signs and symbols used in the natural sciences and technology may require additional spaces (in particular, between the numerical value and the unit symbol). In math mode, use `\` (backslash space) or `~` (tilde) if you want the equivalent of space in normal text. Where separation of numbers into groups of three digits is used, the groups shall be separated by a thin space `\,` (backslash comma); e.g. `$299\,792\,458$` yields $299\,792\,458$.

### Basic chem

We use the [mhchem](https://github.com/mhchem/MathJax-mhchem) package for chemistry. It lets us easily format chemical formulas and reactions without typing too much.

There really is only one command you need to know here: `\ce{...}`. `\ce{...}` takes its parameters and automatically formats it. For example,

```
$\ce{HCl}$ dissociates in water as follows:
$$\ce{H2O + HCl <=> H3O+ + Cl-}$$
```

Renders as

> $\ce{HCl}$ dissociates in water as follows:
>   $$\ce{H2O + HCl <=> H3O+ + Cl-}$$

Note that spaces are very important for mhchem to separate super/subscripts from normal text. `\ce{H3O+}` will display $\ce{H3O+}$, but `\ce{H2O +}` will display $\ce{H2O +}$. When typesetting ions with more than a single charge, the argument has to be raised using the caret (^; also known as the circumflex accent) character, e.g. `$\ce{Cu^2+}$` renders as $\ce{Cu^2+}$, while `$\ce{Cu2+}$` would incorrectly render to $\ce{Cu2+}$. (Also see basic math below.)

Various types of reaction arrows are supported, including `->`, `<=>`, `<==>>`, etc.

It also supports various types of bonds, via the `\bond{..}` command (to be called inside `\ce{...}`). You need not call `\bond` for normal bonds.

Eg: `\ce{H\bond{->}A-B=C#D\bond{~}E\bond{~-}F\bond{...}G\bond{<-}E}` displays:

> $$\ce{H\bond{->}A-B=C#D\bond{~}E\bond{~-}F\bond{...}G\bond{<-}E}$$

[Full documentation of mhchem here](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/)

### Basic math

#### Superscripts and subscripts

You can denote superscripts via the `^` character, and subscripts via `_`. For example, `x^2` renders as $x^2$, `x_1` renders as $x_1$, and `x_1^3` renders as $x_1^3$.

If you want to include more than one character in the super/sub script, enclose it in curly braces (`{...}`).

For example, `x^10` renders as $x^10$, but `x^{10}` renders as $x^{10}$

#### Fractions and square roots

Fractions can be easily displayed using `\frac{..}{..}`. For example, `$$\frac{a+b^c}{de+f}$$` renders as

> $$\frac{a+b^c}{de+f}$$

However, where it is necessary to include fractions in the body text, they shall, where possible, be reduced to a single level by using a solidus (/) or, where applicable, the negative index. For example, instead of $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$ write $1/\sqrt 2$ or $2^{-1/2}$; instead of $C_{\mathrm m,p} = 33.58\ \mathrm{\frac{J}{K \cdot mol}}$ write $C_{\mathrm m,p} = 33.58\ \mathrm{J/(K \cdot mol)}$ or $C_{\mathrm m,p} = 33.58\ \mathrm{J\cdot K^{-1} \cdot mol^{-1}}$.

Protip: You can exclude the braces for single-character numerators/denominators (if the first character is a letter, you need to use a space after `\frac`, though). For example `\frac12` renders as $\frac12$, and `\frac ab` renders as $\frac ab$.

Square roots can be added in a similar manner, via `\sqrt{....}`. For example, `\sqrt{x+y}` renders as $\sqrt{x+y}$.

#### Greek letters

Greek letters can be added using a backslash ('\'), followed by the name of the letter. Captialise the first letter of the name for greek capital letters.

Eg `\alpha \beta \gamma \Omega` renders as $\alpha \beta \gamma \Omega$.

Make sure that you put spaces after these if you are typing normal alphabet characters. Eg `e^{\pii}` gives an error, you need to use `e^{\pi i}`.

Note that there are special commands `\varepsilon , \varsigma , \varrho , and \varpi` to distinguish between the lunate Greek letters.

### MathJax extensions

MathJax has available a variety of extensions enabling other features: strikeout lines, enclosures, text/background coloration, interactive equations, etc. Information about these extensions and how to enable them can be found at [this meta post](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3540/11367).

### Further reading

- [Wikipedia TeX help page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula) (extremely useful as a reference, useless as a tutorial)
- [TeX/LaTeX Stack Exchange site](http://tex.stackexchange.com)
- [Harvard intro to TeX](http://www.math.harvard.edu/texman/)
- [LaTeX wikibook, Math section](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics)
- [LaTeX wikibook, Advanced Math section](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics)

If you would like to know more, you can [continue reading](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/444/7951) about which symbols are written in italic (sloping) type and which are printed in roman (upright) type.

---

<sub>**Note:** As of April 30 2017 the CDN hosting at cdn.mathjax.org was shut down, as a result directories such as https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-third-party-extensions/tree/master/mhchem (like the one appearing in the original of the text below) will 404. According to Issue #39 "[[IMPORTANT] MathJax CDN end-of-life & suggested changes to third-party extensions #39](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-third-party-extensions/issues/39)" all 3rd party extensions will be hosted in separate repositories (one per extensions). See link to Issue #39 for a partial list of the new locations.</sub>

<sub>MathJax/mhchem Extension 3.3 was moved to: https://github.com/mhchem/MathJax-mhchem. The full Mathjax/mhchem is now located at: https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/.</sub>

Answer (score -3):

## Please be careful when using TeX/MathJax in *titles*!

This is more on how *not* to use MathJax, but still good to keep in mind.

A good overview of why not to use do this is given [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1440), but let me briefly summarize:

1. Titles are visible in places that do not render TeX!
2. If you must describe your title with TeX, you probably aren't summarizing your question enough. Try to make a natural language title, that is usually possible and summarizes your question better.
3. If you *insist*, then by all means, use TeX in the title. But there's always room for improvement. IMO, TeX in title is *never* necessary and a sign that the title can be improved!