# How to draw quantum circuits?

Tags: feature-request

We need an easy way to draw quantum circuits as these are fundamental to programming a quantum computer. Ideally, there was some library (like mathjax for LaTeX-like math) that translates a text representation into a decent quantum circuit.

Also, it would be convenient if some LaTeX-like commands (like `\ket{0}` to produce $\left| 0 \right>$) could be enabled.

A trivial example of a quantum circuit (a true random number generator), to illustrate the need:

|0> -----H----(measure)

Comment: Maybe we could request the devs to add a LaTeX package to draw quantum circuits, like [this one](https://www.media.mit.edu/quanta/qasm2circ/) or *maybe* [Quirk](http://algassert.com/2016/05/22/quirk.html) (which is apparently easier to use)

Comment: @Blue I think an inline specialized drawing tool would be better, similar to the one on [ux.se], as more LaTeX packages make the pages render slower. Simple images don't. Alternatively, use another program to draw circuits (I think Inkscape, Ipe or Visio would be decent)

Comment: As for the LaTeX commands and the one requested in particular, see  https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/50 .

Comment: @Blue - Quirk looks interesting but at the bottom of the page the author mentions alternatives, of which LIQ⏐〉 looks to be most useful and best supported: http://stationq.github.io/Liquid/ - with that the examples/question/answer will actually be *runnable* on simulators or hardware.

Comment: There's also the suggestion to use Qcircuit, offered over in Nat's MathJax Q&A: https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/152/278