# Formatting chemical formulae and reactions

Tags: discussion, faq

Following proper typesetting standards is absolutely essential on a technical site like Quantum Computing Stack Exchange.

I came across this question on the main site: [What kinds of ions do trapped ion quantum computers use?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1457/what-kinds-of-ions-do-trapped-ion-quantum-computers-use/) whose [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/1458/26) needed at least a minimal usage of chemical expressions, however initially it was not properly typeset.

---

The LaTeX package `mhchem` is not activated here, by default. However, you can load it yourself, by using the command `\require{\mhchem}` (you need to use it only once on a page).

Example: `\require{\mhchem}\ce{H2O}` generates $\require{\mhchem}\ce{H2O}$.

Courtesy: [@DavidCervone](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10069/enabling-mhchem#comment37970_10069) on Physics SE

---

For further guidance on how to format chemical expressions check this Chemistry SE post: [How can I format math/chemistry expressions here?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)