# How to write a good question?

Tags: discussion, faq

Some of the important points are already well documented on the [help/how-to-ask](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page of the [Help Center](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/help). However, there are a few issues which haven't emphasized there but are particularly relevant for Quantum Computing SE. I'll be summarizing those in [an answer](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/371) below and will probably keep updating it with time. Please feel free to make further suggestions in form of answers or comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Guidance for [new contributors](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314287/come-take-a-look-at-our-new-contributor-indicator?cb=1):

Read through the [help/on-topic](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [help/how-to-ask](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) pages to make sure your question is *answerable* and *on-topic* for our site, in the first place. Also review the Q&As in the [reference](/questions/tagged/reference) list to quickly get acquainted with the [Quantum Computing SE](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/).

### General guidelines for all askers:

Apart from the points mentioned in [help/how-to-ask](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help/on-topic](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), you **must** keep these in mind when asking a question on [Quantum Computing SE](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/):

1. Images or screenshots of text, code and mathematical expressions in Q&As is discouraged all over Stack Exchange (c.f. this [Meta SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052)).
2. Format your posts well; almost everything you might need is summarized in the [editing-help](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/editing-help) page. Please avoid using [bare URLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bare_URLs) in your question (this applies for answers and comments as well). It's good internet etiquette to [dress up bare links](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/editing-help#links) mentioning where they point to.
3. It's *mandatory* to use [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) to properly typeset mathematical expressions when writing Q&As here. Please go through this short [MathJax tutorial](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49).
4. Use *appropriate* [tags](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/tags) for your questions. Read through [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/help/tagging)
5. Use *correct* spelling, punctuation, and grammar to the best of your ability. It's a good idea to check your post for grammar and spelling errors, using an application like [Grammarly](https://app.grammarly.com/), *before* hitting the submit button.
6. State the *exact* source when citing text or images, with attribution. Don't plagiarize. Carefully go through the [How to reference material written by others?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) page in the [help center](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/help).
7. Write [good and descriptive titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647) for your questions. Descriptive titles make it easier to search for old questions and find [duplicates](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates). This takes some mental effort but is absolutely worth it.
8. Always link to the abstract of a paper rather than its PDF. That's helpful for future visitors because:

   - it always leads to the latest version of the paper.
   - it lets them decide whether it is worth their time to download the PDF.
   - a lot of users browse this site on mobile and it's not always convenient for them to download large PDFs.
9. Questions should be *self-contained* as far as possible. Don't expect us to read through a linked textbook or article to answer your question. In other words: you're unlikely to get helpful answers if you're being lazy!

You may consider dropping into [main chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74398/the-classical-channel) *before* asking a question, or in case your question gets put [on hold](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) so that the regular users can guide you appropriately.

---

**Note:** For using [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com) you need a minimum of [20 rep points](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat). In case, you have less rep than, you may request the moderators to give you [Explicit write access](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/74398/the-classical-channel?tab=access) in chat, *after* asking your question, in the comment section of that question. Remember that you can [always comment on your questions and answers, and any answers to questions you've asked, even with 1 rep](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Note that chat requires a minimum rep of 20 to talk.

Answer (score 4):

Some other random points I can think of:

- #### Search before asking

  Perform at least 5 different searches on Google, this Stack Exchange and https://arxiv.org.
- #### Read your post loud.

  This might help you to find mistakes, especially when you are not an English native speaker (like me).
  Remember: Something that sounds awkward is often wrong
- #### Have a goal

  Ask yourself what you want to achieve with your question: What do you
  want to learn? what problem do you want to solve?
- #### Use appropriate tags

  Imagine you have to give up to five one-word answers to complete the
  sentence *My question is about ...*