# Should we add a "not enough research effort" close reason?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, vote-to-close, close-reasons

In [*Homework questions, and what to do about them*](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/194/55) we discussed whether it would be a good idea to have an additional vote-to-close reason.

The consensus/majority seemed to be that it would be a good idea to avoid thinking about whether something constitutes a "homework question", but that questions not showing enough research effort should be closed.

Rather than using other close reasons for this, it would therefore be a good idea to add an additional vote-to-close reason along these lines.
Do we want to do this?

If so, we also need to agree on a specific wording. I don't want to needlessly reinvent the wheel here, as other sites already have such a reason to close questions in place. In particular here are reasons used down on math.SE and physics.SE:

### [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

> This question is missing context or other details: Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

### [physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/)

> Homework-like questions should ask about a specific physics concept and show some effort to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. See our meta site for more guidance on how to edit your question to make it better

### [stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com)

> Self-study questions (including textbook exercises, old exam papers, and homework) that seek to understand the concepts are welcome, but those that demand a solution need to indicate clearly at what step help or advice are needed. For help writing a good self-study question, please visit the meta pages.

Many other sites don't have analogous reasons to vote questions in place (place point them out if you see any, I haven't actually checked them all). At [mathematica.SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com) they have two close reasons along the lines of "*This question arises due to a simple mistake (...)*" and "*(...) question cannot be answered without additional information (...)*" which I would say are the coding equivalent of what would be "*not enough research effort*" for us.

Personally, I am absolutely happy with the math.SE one, and I don't see anything that wouldn't also be perfectly fit for us.

Finally, let me point out that there is an argument to be made that the already existing *unclear what you are asking* reason already covers the *not enough research effort* cases. It could then be a good idea to just adjust the wording of that reason without having to add a wholly new one. I'm not sure whether this is possible at all though, so I'll wait for a mod to pitch in on this one.

---

## Please upvote (downvote) this question if you agree that we should (should not) add an additional vote-to-close reason, and upvote (downvote) the answers to express your opinion on the wording we should use (in the case the overall opinion is to add a reason).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest a slight modification to [the version](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/395/26) [@glS](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/users/55/gls) cited:

> This question is missing context or other details: Please [improve the question](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/371) by providing additional context. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your thoughts and current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

I think the last sentence is essential to include as it justifies why we're asking the OP for more context.

Comment: Oooh, lucky! You were 2 characters short of the limit! This is now an 'official' close reason

Comment: @Mithrandir24601 great! thanks

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would just copy the reason used on math.SE, no need to reinvent the wheel:

> This question is missing context or other details: Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.