# Creation of qcircuit latex quickef

Tags: feature-request

The qcircuit latex package uses the xy-matrix package to create quantum circuits including all types of gates (simple, multi, controlled), a lot of measurement personalization, etc...

[image: This for example]

This is a representation of Grover's Algorithm with a circuit created in latex with qcircuit.

There is a reference PDF created by Bryan Eastin, Steve T Flammia and Travis L Scholten. Despite its excellent quality, I think it would be a good idea to create a qcircuit quickref ([Like the MathJax quickref on meta math exchange](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)). It would help new people to learn about this latex package to help in documents they create. It also would make people able to share knowledge, tips and tricks about the package that is not necessarily shown in the pdf.

Comment: Do you have a link to this reference pdf? If it's very short, I think simply linking it somewhere (such as [our Tex/Mathjax tutorial](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/49/23)) would work, or if the aim is to shorten it down into a simple form, you could add it to an answer to that question, or if it's a bit longer than that, I see no problems with creating a meta post for that purpose (assuming, of course, that other people aren't unhappy with that)

Comment: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/qcircuit?lang=en It is not too long. This package is automatically installed on a lot of systems so finding the docs may not be the easiest things. I just got the idea and wanted to know what the community thought

Answer (score 2):

I see no harm in having a meta post for this, especially if you include examples different than those in the official references. To be honest, I think even only having a quickref that is not in a pdf would be an advantage.

Comment: Ok, I'll do it tomorow then