# Custom link on the mathjax help page

Tags: discussion, status-completed, mathjax, hyperlinks

On the editing help page there is a [MathJax-dedicated section](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex), which includes a "Learn more" link. We've recently been reminded that this link, whose default and current target is https://legacy-www.math.harvard.edu/texman/, can be customised:

[image]

What page should we link to in this help section?

We will regard upvotes/downvotes to an answer as consensus/disagreement with the associated proposal.
Once we reach a consensus on an answer, we'll flag it to the CMs to have them enact the change.

Comment: This has been assigned to a CM to look into, and you'll hear from us once someone picks it up in the near future ^_^

Comment: Hey, I updated the link to point to the suggested tutorial on your meta.

Comment: @SpencerG great, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that we have already a [well-written mathjax meta post](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49/tutorial-how-to-use-tex-mathjax-to-render-math-notation), a natural choice, seems to me, is to just send people there. In other words, to have the "Learn more" link in the editing-help page point to *[Tutorial: How to use TeX/MathJax to render math notation?](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49)*.